# Please help to identify component (From Nest E thermostat base)

Tags: identification

I've just blown the thermostat base by misconnecting wires. 
The component marked on the picture is visibly damaged. Is it possible to identify what that part is?

Thanks.

[image: photo of PCB]

Comment: I recall having something like this happen- I moved the fuse and maybe a transistor over from an unused output to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Ref Des next to the component says F3, so it is most likely a fuse.

If you have some specs on the thermostat you might be able to figure out a reasonable value for a replacement.